# Linq Conversion From ICollection<T> to List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, icollection

I am using Code First Entity Framework.

I am using the following simple classes:

```
public class Users
{
    public ICollection<Projects> Projects{get;set;}
}

public class Projects
{
    public ICollection<Users> Users{get;set;}
}
```

I am using linq for data retrieval.  When performing the following query: (Note that `lstProjects` is a `List<Project>`)

```
var lstUsers = (from users in lstProjects
                where users.ProjectId == pId
                select users.Users).ToList();
```

I have a `List<Users>` object and want to populate this List with items. Like,

```
var lstUsersToDisplay = new List<Users>();
lstUsersToDisplay = (List<Users>)lstUsers; //This can't be cast.
```

What's the approach to convert `ICollection<T>` to `List<T>`?

Secondly, I have `List<Users>` and want to convert it into `ICollection<Users>` how achieve this?

**Edited:**
Scenario, more clearly is that
All `Projects` are loaded in `lstProjects` and we need to select the `Users` which were mapped to a specific project. These Users are also are contained inside `Projects` as collection. Every `Project` has its `Users collection` like if I decomposed the lstProjects it would be like:

`lstProjects --> [0]-->//other Properties
                      ICollection[Users]-->[0]//Contains User class Properties
                                           [1]....
                [1] ... same procedure`

Hope it clears the scenario

Comment: What is `lstProjects`? If it's a `List<Project>` then you've *actually* got a `List<Project>` as `lstUsers`, despite your names. If you hover over the `var` of `var lstUsers` in Visual Studio, what does it show you? And what's the error message? It would *really* help if you'd show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. (Also, why are you creating an empty list and then ignoring it? Why aren't you just using `var lstUsersToDisplay = lstUsers;`?)

Comment: @JonSkeet my appologize in typing basically i am retrieving the users collection from the project list. i have modified it

Comment: So your `users` range variable is actually a `Project`? Holy confusing naming, Batman! It sounds like you've now got a `List<ICollection<Users>>`. Again, you should hover over the `var` to see what you've actually got...

Answer (score 5):

If your query is *genuinely* this:

```
var lstUsers = (from users in lstProjects
                where users.ProjectId == pId
                select users.Users).ToList();
```

then that's equivalent to:

```
List<ICollection<Users>> lstUsers = (from users in lstProjects
                                     where users.ProjectId == pId
                                     select users.Users).ToList();
```

If you're trying to get the list of uses from a *single* project, I'd write that as:

```
var lstUsers = lstProjects.Single(project => project.ProjectId == pId)
                          .Users
                          .ToList();
```

If there could be multiple projects with the same `ProjectId`, you want to flatten the users. For example:

```
var lstUsers = lstProjects.Where(project => project.ProjectId == pId)
                          .SelectMany(project => project.Users)
                          .ToList();
```

Or in query expression syntax:

```
var lstUsers = (from project in lstProjects
                where project.ProjectId == pId
                from user in project.Users
                select user).ToList();
```

Note the fact that my range variable is called `project`, because it refers to a project, *not* a user. Naming is important - pay attention to it. I would also rename the `Projects` and `Users` types to just `Project` and `User`, assuming each is really only meant to represent a single entity.

Comment: Should there be a WHERE in "Or in query expression syntax"?

Comment: nice - but why don't you use the overload to `.Sinlge` that filters too in your 3rd snippet? It looks nicer and is more readable IMHO?

Comment: @bdimag: Doh, yes. Will fix.

Answer (score 0):

`lstUsers` isn't a `List<User>`.  It's a `List<ICollection<User>>`.  You map each project to a *sequence* of users, not to a single user.  To flatten a collection of collections into just a collection of the inner items you would use `SelectMany`, or, in query syntax, you'd write out your query like so:

```
var lstUsers = (from project in lstProjects
                where project.ProjectId == pId
                from user in project.Users
                select user).ToList();
```

*Now* you have a `List<User>` for `lstUsers`.  You can assign that as is to a `List<User>` or an `ICollection<User>`

Answer (score 0):

```cs
using System.Linq; //include extension method OfType<> for ICollection
...
List<Projects> userList = lstUsers.OfType<Projects>().ToList();
```